# Choose the best backend for real-time wbapp

Tags: node.js, django, websocket, openlayers, django-channels

I have a gps tracking service  tha is monitoring data (ex cars) from database on the openlyers map realtime.
I want to use websocket.
So what is the best for backend .
Django channels or nodejs??

I want to use postgresql but django channels use redis.

Answer (score 1):

if u start small project, postgresql also offer pub/sub function.

so u can make beta version appication by using only postgresql.

but if u find best practice for real time application, django channels + aws elastic cache also nice choice.

i think u need just pub/sub function, right?

Comment: No the project is real and big scal.

Comment: https://farhanghazi17.medium.com/deploy-django-channels-websockets-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-using-gunicorn-supervisor-redis-872ce86ba68d

Please refer to it

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answer might **depend on** your **functional and non-functional requirements**.

In accordance with the details you mentioned, I would recommend going with the following setup:

Node.js application based on [npm ws package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) for the **communication layer** and [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) as an **ORM**. This is a bare minimum to start

Nevertheless, additionally, you have to pay attention to the expertise of the team (if exists), further maintenance and deployment...